# How can I select a random region in which run an event?

Tags: java, gis, anylogic

I'm creating a model in which I have to simulate an eartquake. In particular its position would be random within multiple region which I have created on my GIS map. I need to run model and after a few moments, model have to generate a random position of epicenter in South Italy, in one of regions which I created. Moreover, these regions have different probabilities to run an earthquake (for example Campania 20%, Calabria 15%, etc.). How can improve it? I don't know java language as well as, could you guide me on it? Thanks a lot, regards. I've uploaded a pic of my Anylogic model. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are not the same. So what is it you are looking for: Java or JavaScript? Please only add the appropriate tag. In both language you could nevertheless use `Math.random() <= probability` to get `true` or `false` for a given probability

Comment: So `Math.random() <= 0.2` will return `true` in 20% of the invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Java language in Anylogic, I typed javascript by mistake in tags. However, there are more regions which have same probability, for example: "Region A" : 15%, "Region B" : 15%. If I type "Math.random() <= 0.15" how can I know which region is choosen for the earthquake epicenter? There are 10 regions form which choose earthquake epicenter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` will return a pseudorandom number with (approximately) even distribution between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Therefore you can use `Math.random() < probability` to get `true` return if an event with the given probability should happen and `false` if not.

Here an example which also calculates the actual amount of times an earthquake was spawned to show that the probability is actually what you expect.

```java
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var trueCounter = 0;
        var falseCounter = 0;
        var tries = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++){
            var spawnEarthquake = shouldSpawnEarthquake(0.2f);
            if(spawnEarthquake) trueCounter++;
            else falseCounter++;
        }
        System.out.printf("""
                %s tries:
                %s times an earthquake was spawned (Ratio: %s)
                %s times no earthquake was spawned (Ratio: %s)
                """, tries, trueCounter, (double)trueCounter / (double) tries, falseCounter, (double)falseCounter / (double) tries);
    }
    public static boolean shouldSpawnEarthquake(float probability){
        return Math.random() < probability;
    }

}
```

Expected result:

```
10000 tries:
1987 times an earthquake was spawned (Ratio: 0.1987)
8013 times no earthquake was spawned (Ratio: 0.8013)
```

> Your results might obviously differ but should be in the same ballpark.

You would need to iterate over all your regions and apply the function for each region, because earthquakes are not mutual exclusive. If earthquakes would be mutual exclusive your model/ simulation is not very accurate. There is nothing that prevents two earthquakes from happening at the "same time" (at least to my knowledge), so you need to run this probability against all of the regions. You could of course also model something like an decreased probability for an earthquake when an earthquake happens nearby if something like this is actually the case. But that's up to you modelling it, I am no earthquake expert.

Here a simple implementation that checks for an earthquake in a region once. Execute it multiple times to see that sometimes an earthquake will be spawned and sometimes, no earthquake will be spawned:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {
    
    // A record for the region
    // Each region as a name and an earthquake probability
    record Region(String name, float earthquakeProbability){};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var myRegions = List.of(
                new Region("Campania", 0.2f),
                new Region("Calabria", 0.15f)
        );

        myRegions.forEach(region -> {
            var spawnEarthquake = shouldSpawnEarthquake(region.earthquakeProbability);
            if(spawnEarthquake) System.out.printf("An earthquake occurred in %s\n", region.name());
        });
    }
    public static boolean shouldSpawnEarthquake(float probability){
        return Math.random() < probability;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this code you made checks for each region if an earthquake has occurred. Is it correct? And in the end it should tell you in how many regions an earthquake occurred at the same time?

Comment: And how can i understand in which region have been an earthquake?

Comment: No this was essentially just executing the probability function a high number of times so you can see that the probability is actually 20% for an earthquake to be spawned. You would need to have some collection or array of regions you can iterate over and then run the  `shouldSpawnEarthquake()` method for each of these regions. If it returns `true` an earthquake should be happening in that region.

Comment: Ok, but how can I link elements of the collection with my regions which are on GIS map? If I put in my canvas collection item from the palette, I can insert just strings and I can't link these strings (which represent regions name) with my regions that are on GIS map.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea about GIS maps and its Java APIs (which it may or may not have). I've added an example with regions how you could determine in which region an earthquake occurs though, maybe this will help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the help ! I'll try to import this code in my model and see what will happen.

Comment: So, I need to type both code which you have typed, isn't it? The once to count number of earthquake and second one to verify in each region.

Comment: Nope, you would only need the second. But actually both won't probably do much in your environment. Not even sure if your enviroment supports `records` as they are availabe since Java 14. You would need to read yourself on how to interact with the GIS Maps environment. My code is just conceptually what you would need to do.